# SAXParseException on W3C xsd validator

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I can't validate my xml schema [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) .
I have the following error :

> Cannot resolve the name 'familyType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

Here is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="families">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="family" type="familyType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="familyType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="father" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="mother" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify that the `family` element is of type `familyType`, you have to declare a type, not an element, named `familyType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="families">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="family" type="familyType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="familyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="father" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="mother" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```